# Specifies invalid parent id (Magento Backend::mgs)

Tags: magento2, backend

When I installed MGS "Mmegamenu" module in my magento v2.o.5. Frontend is loading fine but when I login to admin panel it is showing the below error :

> Specified invalid parent id `(Magento_Backend::mgs)`
>
> 0 `/var/www/html/magento2sd1/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))`...

Can you please help me in this.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no any parent id name with **mgs** so it will throw error

See below code is for page menu

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" title="Pages" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_block" title="Blocks" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

In above code `parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements"` so it will display in content menu so give valid id to your menu then it will work.

Comment: Thank you soo much prashant Valanda..It is working fine.

Comment: Please share path of this file also

Comment: @SayyedHasan you can add it in menu.xml file of your custom module inside app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

Answer (score 1):

I ran the command below via ssh in the Magento directly which solved the problem for me.

```
php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Core
```

Enabling the Core module of MGS seemed to be the issue. I must have disabled it before by mistake?

After that run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the menu file located under **/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/adminthml/menu.xml**

```
<add id="Magento_Backend::mgs" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::mgs" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
```

Here's how it'll look

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" title="Pages" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_block" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
        <add id="Magento_Backend::mgs" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::mgs" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```