# Magento 2 Admin Page “Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Xtento_XtCore::extensions)”

Tags: third-party-module

I've installed xtento module in magento and I getting this error when I try to display admin login form.

````
``` 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Xtento_XtCore::extensions)```
````

Comment: try this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126505/85907

Comment: Thanks! the mistake was I had not install Xtento_Xtcore first

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install Xtento_Xtcore First, once I've installed it works perfectly.