# Magento2: Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs)

Tags: magento2

I try instlall MGS Shop by Brand.
Frontend working correct. But in backend I get issue:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs)

Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs)
<pre>#1 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#0000000008529c61000000004fa0d711#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#0000000008529c61000000004fa0d711#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#0000000008529c61000000004fa0d711#), array(array('mstCoreBuilder'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:26]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#0000000008529c61000000004fa0d711#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:148]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:111]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:365]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:325]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Go to **MGS/Brand/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml** replace code with this code
> :-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Backend::mgs" title="MGS" module="Magento_Backend" sortOrder="70" resource="Magento_Backend::mgs"/>
        <add id="MGS_Brand::brand" title="Shop By Brand" module="MGS_Brand" sortOrder="80" parent="Magento_Backend::mgs" resource="MGS_Brand::brand"/>
        <add id="MGS_Brand::manage_brand" title="Manage Brands" module="MGS_Brand" sortOrder="10" parent="MGS_Brand::brand" action="brand/brand/" resource="MGS_Brand::manage_brand"/>
        <add id="MGS_Brand::configuration" title="Configuration" module="MGS_Brand" sortOrder="20" parent="MGS_Brand::brand" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/brand" resource="MGS_Brand::configuration"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a parent module isn't enabled or there is missing xml which defines mgs

[Specifies invalid parent id (Magento Backend::mgs)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/126502/62080)

Clearing cache and running setup could be a quick fix